# How to avoid carousel items loading as a list on page build

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a layout for a client which includes a carousel of product icons at the top of every page, the idea being visitors can jump to that section of the site from the carousel. However when loading the page the icons are initially displayed as a list until snapping into place once the page is done.

I've tried things like setting the display to none, then using javascript to show it when the page has loaded and also after the carousel has initialised, but that didn't seem to work.

Understandably the problem is getting worse as the page below gets more complicated. Any bright ideas as to what to try?

The page uses Jquery & Bootstrap with Slick.js for the carousel.

Here's a sample page from the layout: http://www.webeditors.co.uk/se/course.php

Comment: Can you give the carousel a fixed height?

Comment: Just tried that, and curiously none of the items in the carousel appear at all...

Comment: Please: 1) Include the relevant code in your question, because if that site ever changes or goes down your question will be useless to others in the future; 2) Provide a mockup of your code on a site like JS Fiddle or Bootply to properly highlight the error, and to give others a jumpstart in helping you solve the problem.

Comment: @PeteSE4 what css did you add? What about something like this? 

.product-carousel {height: 65px;}

Comment: @AndrewWalters Yup, I added height:121px to the parent <section>; although an update to that - just refreshed the page again and the icons do appear, although they load *over* the rest of the page, so I'm going to play with the overflow settings and hope that doesn't screw up the carousel functionality.

Comment: I'm sure the carousel library will have a callback function. Hide the carousel with CSS, and show it in the callback function

Comment: Just like the pain going away when you go to the doctor, I think I've cracked it. My initial thought of hiding the carousel while the page is building was correct, I was just using the wrong method. Dumb error - I was using `display: hidden;` rather than `visibility`. Now I've changed that (and the JQuery code to show it afar the carousel has initialised), it seems to work. Many thanks for the tips above that helped me look at my code a bit more clearly. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could add setTimeout() for the carousel and then display the images with style.display = "block" or removing a "hide" class after the timeout.

I don't know how you've styled the icons, but could you style them with UL and float the LIs

```
<ul>
    <li><img><li>
    <li><img><li>
</ul>

li {
    float: left;
}
```

This way they should be in place when page loads. CSS is faster than JS.